# Cannot import rq use_connect on docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, redis, dokku

I have Django application running on dokku and keep getting an rq import error message once I link the postgresql database to the dokku app. I do not understand why I am getting this error now, as I have documented the steps I took to deploy this app in the past, and I followed them exactly to deploy it again.

I deploy my dokku app, then I get blue screened because it relies on redis and postgres. From there I link redis, which does not show an error on redeploy. Then I link my new postgres database and it throws the following error:

```
       20:12:02 system                 | web.1 started (pid=31)
       20:12:02 system                 | default_worker.1 started (pid=35)
       20:12:02 system                 | archive_expired_jobs.1 started (pid=37)
       20:12:02 system                 | badgr_sync.1 started (pid=41)
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     main()
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     utility.execute()
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django_rq/management/commands/rqworker.py", line 6, in <module>
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       |     from rq import use_connection
       20:12:08 default_worker.1       | ImportError: cannot import name 'use_connection'
       20:12:08 system                 | default_worker.1 stopped (rc=1)
       20:12:08 system                 | sending SIGTERM to web.1 (pid 31)
       20:12:08 system                 | sending SIGTERM to archive_expired_jobs.1 (pid 37)
       20:12:08 system                 | sending SIGTERM to badgr_sync.1 (pid 41)
       20:12:08 system                 | archive_expired_jobs.1 stopped (rc=-15)
       20:12:08 system                 | badgr_sync.1 stopped (rc=-15)
       20:12:08 system                 | web.1 stopped (rc=-15)
=====> End uwf-server (f353df3ecff8) container output
-----> Checking for postdeploy task
       No postdeploy task found, skipping
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> Application deployed:
       http://3.23.111.72
```

I am completely dumbfounded. This application is running with the exact same code and dockerfile on another EC2 instance and I have stood it up before using the same exact steps. Django-rq is also in the requirements.txt folder so I know its being added to the environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django rq use connection depreciated in a recent update. To fix the issue I had to update my Django rq version to 2.8.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is because `django-rq` installs `rq` as a dependency, and `django-rq` tries to import the deprecated function `use_connection` from the rq library, which then results in this error.

To make it work, either upgrade `django-rq` to 2.8.0 or add the following in your requirements file:
`rq==1.13.0`

This would pin `rq` to a version for which the function is still supported, and hence you would see no errors.